# Can I autogenerate Storybook component Controls for some stories, but not others?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I love how with the new [Component Story Format](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/csf), controls get generated automatically using `react-docgen-typescript` from component I provide in config:

```js
export default {
  title: 'story name',
  component: MyComponent
} as Meta
```

But with some components, I would like to only use this auto-generated list of Controls for some stories, and not for others.

Maybe like having one story with the full list of Controls for all possible props, and multiple additional Stories that only showcase props that are relevant to the story. This would be especially welcome for stories of custom wrappers over large 3rd party components, that often have hundreds of niche props.

How can I do this?

Comment: Might look at https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11638#issuecomment-748960626